# How to use different axis scales in pandas' DataFrame.plot.hist?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I find `DataFrame.plot.hist` to be amazingly convenient, but I cannot find a solution in this case.

I want to plot the distribution of many columns in the dataset. The problem is that pandas retains the same scale on all x axes, rendering most of the plots useless. Here is the code I'm using:

```
X.plot.hist(subplots=True, layout=(13, 6), figsize=(20, 45), bins=50, sharey=False, sharex=False)
plt.show()
```

And here's a section of the result:
[image: plots]

It appears that the issue is that pandas uses the same bins on all the columns, irrespectively of their values. Is there a convenient solution in pandas or am I forced to do it by hand?

I centered the data (zero mean and unit variance) and the result improved a little, but it's still not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options, here is the code and output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dummy data - value ranges differ a lot between columns
X = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(18):
    X['COL0{0}'.format(i+38)]=(2**i)*np.random.random(1000)

# Method 1 - just using the hist function to generate each plot
X.hist(layout=(3, 6), figsize=(20, 10), sharey=False, sharex=False, bins=50)
plt.title('Method 1')
plt.show()

# Method 2 - generate each plot separately
cols = plt.cm.spectral(np.arange(1,255,13))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,6,figsize=(20,10))
for index, column in enumerate(X.columns):
    ax = axes.flatten()[index]
    ax.hist(X[column],bins=50, label=column, fc=cols[index])
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    ax.set_ylim((0,1.2*ax.get_ylim()[1]))
fig.suptitle('Method 2')
fig.show()
```

The first plot:
[image]

The second plot:
[image]

I would definitely recommend the second method as you have *much* more control over the individual plots, for example you can change the axes scales, labels, grid parameters, and almost anything else.

I couldn't find anything that would allow you to modify the original **plot.hist** bins to accept individually calculated bins.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with the second method, but I had to remove some subplots since the number of columns didn't fit the grid exactly. I used `fig.delaxes` to delete unused subplots. I don't know if there's another way because with the first method you showed there are no axes in excess, but there's no mention of `delaxes` in Pandas' codebase.

Comment: You could also use **fig.add_subplot** to add axes to the figure, see here for example https://pythonprogramming.net/subplot2grid-add_subplot-matplotlib-tutorial/. Glad it helped!